# Understanding Data.Function.on type signature

Tags: haskell, type-signature

I'm still a beginner when it comes to Haskell syntax and functional programming languages so when I look at the type declaration for `Data.Function.on` which is `on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c`, my interpretation is that it takes four parameters: `(b -> b -> c)`, `(a -> b)`, `a`, `a`, and returns `c`. However, when I look at the general use syntax for `Data.Function.on` which is `` (*) `on` f = \x y -> f x * f y ``, it is only taking two function parameters, not four, so how does the type signature relate to the usage syntax?

Comment: The `(->)` is right-associative, so `(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c` is equivalent to `(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> c)`. Notice the parentheses around the `a -> a -> c` at the end.

Comment: It is equivalent to `on (*) f x y = f x * f y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Haskell arrow for function types hides a simple but clever idea. You have to think of `->` as an operator, like `+` and `-`, but for types. It takes two types as arguments and gives you a new type consisting of a function. So in

```
Int -> String
```

You have the types `Int` and `String`, and you get a function from an Int to a String.

Just like any other operator, you need a rule for a chain of them. If you think of `-`, what does this mean?

```
10 - 6 - 4
```

Does it mean `(10 - 6) - 4 = 0`, or does it mean `10 - (6 - 4) = 8`? The answer is the first one, which is why we say that `-` is "left associative".

The `->` operator is right associative, so

```
foo :: Int -> String -> String
```

actually means

```
foo :: Int -> (String -> String)
```

Think about what this means. It means that `foo` doesn't take 2 arguments and return a result of type `String`, it actually takes 1 argument (the `Int`) and returns a new function that takes the second argument (the `String`) and returns the final `String`.

Function application works the same way, except that is left associative. So

foo 15 "wibble"

actually means

(foo 15) "wibble"

So `foo` is applied to `15` and returns a new function which is then applied to `"wibble"`.

This leads to a neat trick: instead of having to provide all the parameters when you call a function (as you do in just about every other programming language), you can just provide the first one or the first few, and get back a new function that expects the rest of the parameters.

This is what is happening with `on`. I'll use a more concrete version where 'f' is replaced by 'length'.

(*) `on` length

you give `on` its first two parameters. The result is a new function that expects the other two. In types,

```
on :: (b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> a -> a -> c
```

In this case `(*)` has type `Num n => n -> n -> n` (I'm using different letters to make this less confusing), so that is matched with the type of the first argument to `on`, leading to the conclusion that if type `b` is substitued by `n` then type `c` must be as well, and and must also be a `Num` instance. Therefore `length` must return some numeric type. As it happens the type of `length` is `[d] -> Int`, and `Int` is an instance of `Num`, so that works out. So at the end of this you get:

```
(*) `on` length :: [d] -> [d] -> Int
```

Answer (score 5):

> my interpretation is that it takes four parameters

All Haskell functions take one argument. Some of them just return other functions.

The best way to look at the signature for `on` is as a higher-order function: `(b -> b -> c) -> (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> c)`. This says "if you give me a binary operator that takes `b`s and gives a `c` and a way to get `b`s from `a`s, I will give you a binary operator that takes `a`s and gives a `c`". You can see this in the definition:

```
(*) `on` f = \x y -> f x * f y
```

Answer (score 0):

As an intuitive aid, I read this as "if you give me a *comparator* of type `b`, and a way to extract values of type `b` from values of type `a`, I will give you a *comparator* of type `a`".

E.g. if `a` is some composite data type and `b` is some numerical attribute of these data values, you can express the idea of sorting these composite data types by using `Data.Function.on`.